# Adding groups dynamically to list view not reflected after notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm new to android development (an iOS developer) and I am using a BaseExpandableListAdapter for my list view. I am adding 2 more groups to the list (amongst other things) and then calling notifyDataSetChanged and the 2 new groups appear, but show as empty. I have put log statements into some of the implemented adapter methods and I can see that sure enough, it is not asking about the length of the 2 groups I've added.

Here are some log messages illustrating whats happening...

> there are 2 groups - getGroupCount()
>
> there are 5 children in group 0 - getChildrenCount()
>
> there are 1 children in group 1 - getChildrenCount()

notifyDataSetChanged();

> there are 4 groups - getGroupCount()
>
> there are 4 children in group 0 - getChildrenCount()
>
> there are 6 children in group 1 - getChildrenCount(

...doesn't try to ask how many children are in groups 2 and 3?

Thankyou

Comment: It would help if you post the code for your custom adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out groups are added collapsed by default, and I just had to go through each group and ensure it was expanded. This was my code to do just that.

```
    public void expandAllGroups(MyActivity activity)
{
    ExpandableListView list = (ExpandableListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.MyList);
    for (int i = 0; i < activity.adapter.getGroupCount(); i++)
    {
        list.expandGroup(i);
    }
}
```